# Select text being cut off horizontally by arrow

Tags: html, css

I am creating a customised HTML select element, but the text label of the element is being cut off on the right side by the arrow.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
select {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #4b8df4;
}

select:focus {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>50</option>
</select>
```

I am aware of the option of adding `appearance: none` to remove the arrow, but I think keeping the appearance as default is better in terms of cross-browser support.

How can I fix the text from being cut off on the right side without increasing the width? Perhaps by styling the shadow dom if possible?

Comment: Is the set width mandatory? Removing it would fix it

Comment: 2 suggestions: increase the `width` of the select or decrease the left/ right `padding`

Comment: I am aiming to have the width set as is

Comment: Consider reducing font size as well if changing the padding isn't enough

Comment: Either remove the `width` property or increase the value.

Comment: You're forcing the width of the element, and it's not wide enough. If you can't change the width of the element, you just have to reduce the `font-size` but consider that is harmful and not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease your `padding` or increase your `width` or simply remove your width.
i decreased the padding and removed the width here

```css
select {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #4b8df4;
}

select:focus {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>50</option>
</select>
```